# Required Bootstrap scripts and CSS files to hide success message AND to have a tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I am working on an asp.net mvc web application, i already have Bootstrap v2.0.4 script files and css files included in my project but i have never referenced them.

The associated scripts are :-

[image]

The associated css files are:-

[image]

today i wrote the following script, to show a modal popup:-

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

            $(document).on('click', 'a[data-modal]', function (e){
            $('#myModalContent').css({ "max-height": screen.height * .82, "overflow-y": "auto" }).load(this.href, function () {
                $('#myModal').modal({
```

but i got an the following error:-

```
Line: 623
Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'modal'
```

so i have included the following script and i got the modal working well.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
```

Now i need 2 extra bootstrap features, that are :-

1.I added the following tabs to my view, but when i click on any of the tabs nothing will happen:-

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
<li class="active"><a href="#publish">Publish</a></li>
    <li ><a href="#addcustomer">Add Customer</a></li>

</ul>
<div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">

<div class="tab-pane " id="addcustomer">
<a data-modal=''>  oooo</a>
</div>

</div></div>
```

2.hide a success message that is displayed as follow. currently if i click on the close link the message will stay displayed:-

```
 <div class ="alert alert-success">        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
```

so can anyone adivce which css and script files i need to add to get the tabs & hide the success message working ?

Comment: HOLY PLUG-INS! Never seen so many in one project!

Comment: @dowomenfart but i am not referencing them ,, what is the problem of having all of them..

Comment: There's a javascript component to the tabs: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs, and did you even try anything to hide the alert?

Comment: @Chad but as i know the tab class class="tab-pane " is a bootstrap class and so why the tabs is not working ?

Comment: Adding that class provides the CSS for the class, but you need to fire the javascript: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs-usage

Comment: @Chad not sure if i understand your answer, so what i need to include in this case , i mean which bootstrap css and bootstrap javascript i need to include to have the tabs working ?

Comment: You need bootstrap-tab.js and you need to add event binding to your tabs: `$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).tab('show')
})`

Comment: but i should not add any event binding to the tabs ,, it should work out of the box i think, once i include the script  ?

Comment: @johnG No. It needs the javascript. I think I said that.